# Error when serializing JSON "keyNotFound"

Tags: json, swift, codable

I'm practicing the new way of parsing JSON in Swift 4 and I'm using the New York Times API - I'm finding it hard to read the structure of the JSON since the API page just [shows a wall of text](http://api.nytimes.com/svc/topstories/v1/business.json?api-key=f4bf2ee721031a344b84b0449cfdb589:1:73741808)

I've written out a small struct for the data I want to pull (titles, abstracts):

```
struct Stories: Decodable {
    let title: String
    let abstract: String
}
```

and here's the function I call to get the JSON:

```
func getJSON() {
    let jsonUrlString = "https://api.nytimes.com/svc/topstories/v1/business.json?api-key=f4bf2ee721031a344b84b0449cfdb589:1:73741808"
    guard let url = URL(string: jsonUrlString) else {return}

    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, err) in

        guard let data = data else {return}

        do {

            let stories = try
                JSONDecoder().decode(Stories.self, from: data)
            print(stories.title, stories.abstract)

        } catch let jsonErr {
            print("Error serializing JSON", jsonErr)
        }
    }.resume()
}
```

When I run the app, I see my error message in the console:

```
Error serializing JSON keyNotFound(CodingKeys(stringValue: "title", intValue: nil), Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [], debugDescription: "No value associated with key CodingKeys(stringValue: \"title\", intValue: nil) (\"title\").", underlyingError: nil))
```

So it looks like it's not finding the values of "title". What can I do differently here, did I set up the Struct incorrectly? Or am I using JSONDecorder wrong?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: "I'm finding it hard to read the structure of the JSON since the API page just shows a wall of text": Use a Safari/Chrome or else extension that can format pretty/beautify) the JSON, or use an online tool to do so by doing a copy/paste of its content. First, you are missing the fact that there is a key `results` to pass before, and that it's an array of Stories (not a single one).

Comment: Try here http://jsonlint.com

Comment: Thanks Ashley Mills I'll definitely have that site bookmarked. I was getting a headache trying to figure out how it was structured

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that the `Stories` are nested in an outer `Dictionary`, which you also need to parse.

```
struct TopStoriesResponse: Codable {
    let status:String
    let results:[Story]
}

struct Story: Codable {
    let title: String
    let abstract: String
}

func getTopStories() {
    let jsonUrlString = "https://api.nytimes.com/svc/topstories/v1/business.json?api-key=f4bf2ee721031a344b84b0449cfdb589:1:73741808"
    guard let url = URL(string: jsonUrlString) else {return}

    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, err) in

        guard let data = data, err == nil else {
            print(err!)
            return
        }

        do {
            let response = try JSONDecoder().decode(TopStoriesResponse.self, from: data)
            print(response.results.first?.title, response.results.first?.abstract)

        } catch let jsonErr {
            print("Error serializing JSON", jsonErr)
        }
    }.resume()
}
```

Comment: I see, that's definitely where I was going wrong! After using the link Ashley Mills gave me the JSON is much easier to read, I didn't realize it was nested like that. Thanks for the suggestions - although I'm getting an error beside `struct TopStoriesResponse: Codable`, saying that it does not conform to protocol Encodable.

Comment: @KingTim my bad, that was a typo from my side, check my updated answer. Made `Story` conform to `Decodable` instead of `Codable` accidentally.

Comment: Ok seems to work now, except it's only printing one title/abstract.Wouldn't the [Story] array grab all of them?

Comment: @KingTim check my code more carefully, I'm only printing it for the first element :) You can simply do `print(response.results)` if you want to print all.

Comment: Ok I see, thanks. To clarify, I was trying to ultimately get an array of all the titles and an array of all the abstracts (so I can put them into a table view). If I make a variable, say, `var headlines = [String]()`, how would I pull only the titles from the JSON during the data request so I can append them all to that array?

Comment: @KingTim you don't need to separate the data into several arrays, you can simply do in your table view data source methods something like `response.results[indexPath.row].title`. If you really wanted to, you can use `map` like `let headLines = response.results.map{$0.title}`.

Comment: I didn't think I can use `response` in the table view methods, wouldn't I have to cast the response results to a variable outside the `getTopStories()` call? I call that function in `viewDidLoad`, so my plan was to populate those arrays with the response results and then use them to fill the table view. Sorry if this all sounds amateur, like I said this is a practice project to get used to this stuff. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @KingTim of course you'd have to pass the array outside from your network request. You should look into how to return a value from a network request, since it's an async method, so you can't just use a `return` statement